# Include a link into the outgoing email for the report in Cognos

Tags: cognos

I'm trying to schedule a report and send the link via email to the recipients. But when I add a hyper link to the editor it takes it as a plain text. I'm using the following format:

```
<a href="LINK HERE">Click Here</a>
```

Does anyone know if this is even possible? If Cognos would take extra HTML attributes than the ones presented in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out and make sure you drag HTML Item from toolbox

```
 <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Subject Goes Here">Send Mail</a>
```